# Spring data - modifying queries and ehcache (cache)

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-data

Is it possible to make spring data modifying query such as:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1 where u.lastname = ?2")
int setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);
```

Auto invalidate my ehcache of User entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if you declare the User entity as cached using for example a `READ_WRITE` cache concurrency strategy:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User {
    ...
}
```

In such case the cache invalidation will be taken care automatically by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Spring Cache abstraction documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). It basically allows you to configure *what* to cache/evict where and completely configure which cache provider to be used in your application configuration.

Note, that this will cache on the annotated method level.

Comment: This solution feels much more demanding in regard to code changes. we want to alter our current code base as less as possible

Comment: What do you mean with "demanding"? You were showing a repository method, which clearly makes the impression you want to manage cache invalidation at exactly that level. If you're looking for a solution closer to what you have already, you should update the question accordingly. We can just judge from what you show :).